# How can i set the background cell values color using **.push** array in app script?

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have been trying to change the background color of the cell value based on the **STATUS**. If the status is **OLD FILE** then i would like to set the background color of the cell **red**, and if the status is **NEW FILE**, i would like to set it into **green** (as shown in the sample).

[image]

Here is the code:

```
const cells = sheet.getRange("I2:I" + sheet.getLastRow())
const cellValues = cells.getValues()
Logger.log(cellValues)

const newValues = []
var backGrounds = []

cellValues.forEach((row) => {
  if (row[0] === "new file") {
     newValues.push(['OLD FILE'])
   }
   else if (row[0] === "OLD FILE" || row[0] === "NEW FILE") {
     newValues.push([row[0]])
   }
   else {
     newValues.push(['NEW FILE'])
     backGrounds.push(['00ff00'])
   }
   })

   cells.setValues(newValues).setBackground(backGrounds)
   }
```

I have tried using the `backGrounds.push(['00ff00'])` and `.setBackground(backGrounds)` but it still not changing.

How can i change the the cell background color based on the status?

Comment: No need for apps script, much easier to use [conditional fomatting](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/78413?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop#zippy=%2Cexample) in google sheets

Comment: if you don't want to use conditional formatting then you will most likely need an onEdit() function and a table values and colors for those values.  It's not complex but the conditional formating probably operates much faster

Comment: @skara9 Thank you so much for the guide. It is totally a new knowledge for me to learn about. Thanks

Comment: @Cooper Thanks for replying. Yes indeed the conditional formatting method was way much faster and effective.